# Magento 2 : custom controller with multiple functions (actions)

Tags: magento2, controllers

i need index controller file in that i need to write addaction,deleteaction,getinfo,updateaction, like this place code multiple functions.same as like magento 1
after thaif i want add data can call add action if want update data i will directly to update action like this i am asking

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran i will accept but not use full for me what i am looking is completely different

Comment: Please be clear on what you require @pawankumar multiple action in the means. I can' get there

Comment: @Pawankumar, Magento 2 controller execute is one of primary function, Whenever you call the controller this primary function will execute, so as per the Magento 2 multiple actions is not possible as like you want, the prathap answer is better way to achieve your goal based on the condition

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create multiple function in controller execute function

try this,

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    if ($post['hidden_input'] == 'add'){
    $this->add();  // calling add function, if form hidden input is addition
    }else if ($post['hidden_input'] == 'update'){
    $this->update();  // calling update function, if form hidden input is update
    }else {
    $this->delete();  // calling delete function, if form hidden input is deletion
    }
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}

protected function add(){   // function one
       echo "Add function";
}

protected function update(){   // function two
       echo "Update function";
}

protected function delete(){   // function three
       echo "Delete function";
}
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If excute i think all functions will excute

Comment: Yes it will execute all functions, whatever functionalities you want that you can add it.

Comment: No I wan excute only one function based which i called if i call three function only that i need to excute

Comment: You can define different functionalities like that and you can call in execute method whichever you would prefer to use there.

Comment: I have written based if conditions only i thought magento 2 having that functionality